# Is this graph problem NP-Hard?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, nonlinear-optimization

I had asked this question in [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375396/is-this-graph-problem-np-hard?noredirect=1#comment6946013_3375396) without any success

Let $A$ be the symmetric $n\times n$ adjacency matrix for a graph where $A_{ij}$ is the positive edge value between node $i$ and $j$ (thus fully connected graph). Among the $n-$ nodes, let $c$ be a given node of interest (called a central node in my problem). Define the matrix
\begin{align}
B_{ij}=\begin{cases} 0 &,~~i=j \\ \frac{A_{ij}}{A_{ic}A_{jc}} &,~~\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Thus the individual elements are proportional to distance between $i$ and $j$ and inversely proportional to distance from the central node. Thus, this term will be high for pairs which are close to central node, but far from each other.
I am interested in solving the following optimization problem
\begin{align}
\max_{x_{ij}}\sum_{i,j}x_ix_j&B_{ij} 
\\s.t.~~\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\leq K ~~,&~~x_i\in\{0,1\}
\end{align}
Intuitively, I need to select $K$ nodes such that they are as close as possible to the central node yet far apart among themselves?

Is this problem studied in literature? Is it NP-Hard? what are the known practical approaches? I am familiar with the Semidefinite formulation of this. I am interested in knowing if there are graph based approaches.

Comment: There is a natural local search or MCMC you can try as a practical approach, although as Bullet51s answer shows it won't always succeed. The states of the chain are your set of $K$ nodes. A move of the Markov chain (or local search) is to randomly update the position of one of the nodes using your objective function. However, since clique is a special case, and clique is hard to approximate you'll need to impose more structure on the graph to prove an approximation bound. Can you solve the problem on trees / bounded treewidth? Anyhow, maybe worth coding and trying MCMC optimization heuristics.

Comment: You may have more luck here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com or here: https://or.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is at least as hard as the [clique problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem): Take a graph $G$. Let $G'$ be a new graph with vertices $V(G)+c$ and edges $E(G)+\{(g,c)|g\in V(G)\}$.

Let $A_{ij}=1$ if $ij$ is an edge in $G'$, and $0.5$ otherwise. As $A_{ic}=1$ for all vertices $i$, we have

\begin{align}
B_{ij}=\begin{cases} 0 &,~~i=j \\ A_{ij} &,~~\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Finding a solution of $K(K-1)$ to your maximizing problem is equivalent to finding a $K$-clique in the graph $G'$, which corresponds to a $(K-1)$-clique in $G$.

Comment: Is the clique problem NP-hard?

Comment: The problem of finding a clique is NP-hard.

Comment: so can we conclude that a specific instance of my problem is NP-Hard and so the problem itself is?

Comment: also, Please note that graph in question is a fully connected graph. Thus any $K$ subset is a clique. Does that change anything

Comment: The clique problem in $G'$ corresponds to finding a subgraph in $A$ with all edges weighted $1$.